# Do not proceed if the requested permissions are not granted

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I want to publish my **kivy** app for mobile but as I was testing it out I realized a problem.

In the **build method** of my app I ask for three permissions:

- **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**
- **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**
- **INTERNET**

In my app I scan the user's **default downloads directory (using plyer)** to extract audio files available on the user's device. When I deployed it on Android, I did get the popup that asked for the permission but before I could hit ***accept*** my program had already started the search and as a result, the program crashed.

How can I tell my app **NOT** to proceed if the user has not granted permission?

A simple overview of my app:

```
import os
from plyer import storagepath
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
# The rest of my program...
''')

    def build(self):
        if platform == "android":
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

            # I do not want my program to proceed if it doesn't have the requested permissions
            # mostly, read and write permissions
            request_permissions([
                Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Permission.INTERNET
            ])
        return self.kv

    def on_start(self):
        # I start the search here.
        for file in os.listdir(storagepath.get_downloads_dir()):
            if file.endswith("mp3"):
                pass
                # ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: What about instead of asking for the permissions inside the `build` method of your `App`, you can ask for the permissions _before_ the `MainApp` class definition?

Comment: create an empty screen as a first screen and ask for all the permissions u want if True u can switch to ur main screen